# Opencv Mat addition strange behaviour

Tags: opencv, matrix, casting

Why  this 2 lines of code are not equivalent? because of some saturation cast?

Type of Mat's is CV_8U, bgr is vector of 1 channel Mat's, and gray is one channel image.

```
vector<Mat> bgr;
Mat gray;
```

1

```
gray+= (bgr[0]-128)*2;
```

2

```
gray= (bgr[0]-128)*2+gray;
```

Here is a minimal code for reproducing:

```
void Test()
{
    Mat A= Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
    A(Rect(20,20,60,60)).setTo(128);
    Mat R= Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
    randu(R, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));

    //v1
    //A+= (R-128)*2;
    //v2
    A= A+(R-128)*2;

    imwrite("A.png", A);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **YES**, it's because of `saturate_cast`.

---

Basically, in your version 1 you are doing:

```
Mat1b gray; 
// ... gray somehow initialized
Mat1b temp = saturate_cast<uchar>(bgr * 2 - 256);
gray += temp;
```

while in your version 2 you're doing:

```
Mat1b gray; 
// ... gray somehow initialized
gray = saturate_cast<uchar>((2 * bgr + 1 * gray) - 256);
```

You see that `saturate_cast` operates in different places. To avoid this kind of problem, my recommendation is to use always *version 2*, where all computation is done on `double` values, and the cast happens only at the end.

The code should illustrate this:

```
    #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
    using namespace cv;

    int main()
    {
        Mat1b bgr(10, 10, uchar(100));
        Mat1b gray1(10, 10, uchar(100));
        Mat1b gray2(10, 10, uchar(100));
        Mat1b gray3(10, 10, uchar(100));
        Mat1b gray4(10, 10, uchar(100));

        // *****************************************
        // v1
        // *****************************************

        gray1 += (bgr - 128) * 2;

        // MatExpr e1(a = bgr, alpha = 1, beta = 0, s = -128) <- MatExpr operator - (bgr, 128);     // (bgr - 128)
        // MatExpr e2(a = bgr, alpha = 2, beta = 0, s = -256) <- MatExpr operator * (e1, 2);        // (bgr - 128) * 2 -> bgr * 2 - 256
        // Mat_<uchar>& operator += (bgr, e2);

        // temp = saturate_cast<uchar>(bgr * 2 - 256);
        // gray += temp;

        // *****************************************
        // v2
        // *****************************************

        gray2 = (bgr - 128) * 2 + gray2;

        // MatExpr e1(a = bgr, alpha = 1, beta = 0, s = -128) <- MatExpr operator - (rgb, 128);             // (bgr - 128)
        // MatExpr e2(a = bgr, alpha = 2, beta = 0, s = -256) <- MatExpr operator * (e1, 2);                // (bgr - 128) * 2 -> = bgr * 2 - 256
        // MatExpr e3(a = bgr, b = gray, alpha = 2, beta = 1, s = -256) <- MatExpr operator + (e2, gray);   // (bgr - 128) * 2 + gray -> (2 * bgr + 1 * gray)   - 256 

        // gray = saturate_cast<uchar>((2 * bgr + 1 * gray) - 256);


        // *****************************************
        // v3 equivalent to v1
        // *****************************************

        Mat1b temp3 = (bgr - 128) * 2;
        gray3 = gray3 + temp3;


        // *****************************************
        // v4 equivalent to v2
        // *****************************************

        Mat1d bgrd;
        bgr.convertTo(bgrd, CV_64F);
        Mat1d temp4 = (bgrd - 128) * 2;
        Mat1d gray4d;
        gray4.convertTo(gray4d, CV_64F);
        gray4d = gray4d + temp4;
        gray4d.convertTo(gray4, CV_8U);

        // gray1 == gray3
        // gray2 == gray4

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: don't understand why - 256 ?

Comment: That's how it's actually computed... check into the comments of the posted code... `(bgr - 128) * 2 -> bgr * 2 - 256`. Let me know if it's clear

Comment: I thought that brackets define the order of expression evaluation.

Comment: @mrgloom Well, yes. The problem here is not the order of calculations, but the assignment to the gray matrix. When you assign, OpenCV performs the conversion to the same type of the destination matrix, and in your case this cause the issue since the partial results of your operations exceed `uchar` range. In your two versions, the assignment to matrix is performed differently, and so different results.

Comment: The question is when saturate cast is applied? for example expression B=(A-128)+128, if A have pixels <=128 after -128 these pixels became 0, and after +128 them will be 128, but if we uncover brackets we have B=A+0, so no elemets will change. What I mean v1 B=saturate_cast(saturate_cast(A-128)+128) or v2 B=saturate_cast((A-128)+128)=saturate_cast(A+0)?

Comment: `saturate_cast` is applied when there is an assignment to a matrix (`=`). Internally `MatExpr` computes on a data type that won't saturate (in this case is `float` (I just put `double` in my example to be more general)). So what's really happening is that all you matrix operations are stored in a `MatExpr` object, which is evaluated without saturation when there is an assignment. During the assignment the result is saturated to fit the destination matrix.

Comment: @mrgloom so as I mentioned: V1: `Mat1b temp = saturate_cast<uchar>(bgr * 2 - 256); gray += temp;` while in V2: `gray = saturate_cast<uchar>((2 * bgr + 1 * gray)   - 256)`. All the computation is done on a proper data type (`float` here), and then casted to `uchar`.

Comment: @Miki I just noticed the saturate cast happening on assignment. While it is very useful and intuitive indeed, do you happen to know whether it is described anywhere. I fail to see it in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html).